# Symfony2 - Instantiation of arguments in Services

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I'm having a bit of an issue and I don't know if I'm being completely stupid, over imaginative, or if I didn't quite get the grasp of Services.

say I have a Service defined as followed :

```
awesome:
    class: "\\My\\Bundle\\Services\\Awesome"
    arguments:
        fantabulous: @fanta.bulous #which refers to \\Another\\Bundle\\Services\\Fantabulous
```

say I have a controller TestController in which I have the following action

```
public function someAction()
{
    $awesome = $this->get('awesome');
    $awesome->doSomething();
}
```

say the Fantabulous class looks like this :

```
class Fantabulous
{
    protected $number;

    public function __construct($anyNumber)
    {
        $this->number = $anyNumber;
    }

    public function printNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }
}
```

say the Awesome Service looks like this :

```
class Awesome
{
    protected $fantabulous;

    public function __construct(Fantabulous $fantabulous)
    {
        $this->fantabulous = $fantabulous;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        echo $this->fantabulous->printNumber();
    }
}
```

My question now : how do I pass any number (e.g. 14) to initialize Fantabulous, from my TestController? I've been searching high and low for an answer but couldn't find one, it seems to me that everyone never instatiate anything in Services.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't! Not exactly in this case. You cannot call any service from Service Container and pass arguments at same time. However, you can follow these approaches:

1. Add a `setter` method to Fantabulous (maybe Fantabulous::setNumber()) and
   turn optional $anyNumber argument (on construct);
2. Create objects on hand rather call it from container;
3. Create a [factory](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/dependency_injection/factories.html) service in order to create "Awesome" or others
   services;

What you want has already been [discussed](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4142) once the project repository, you might want to take a look and find out why the suggestion was not approved.
Helpful links:

- [Using a Factory to Create Services](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/dependency_injection/factories.html)
- [[RFC][2.2][DIC] Specify service constructor parameters from code #4142](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4142)

Comment: Well, that's disapointing. 
1. I don't see how this would solve anything as I don't have control over Awesome. 2. I don't want to modify the vendor itself because I don't think that's the way to do things.
3. From what I've read, it doesn't provide me with a solution to pass arguments from my controller. I'm quite surprised nobody had a use case like this one, it seems rather straight forward. Say I have a form with the action set to someAction(), how can I pass form data to initialize Fantabulous so as it's usable by Awesome. That's my question.

Comment: @JulienLachal That isn't as "nobody had a use case like this one". It just means what you're trying it is a wrong approach. If a "service" require dynamic arguments values, IT NOT SHOULD BE A SERVICE! It should be something like "utility" (My\Bundle\Util\MyClass maybe).
I'm almost sure your "service" is not a good candidate for a service in fact.